# Why would SVN not merge what diff shows?

Tags: svn

I have a single working copy. BASE is r1901, HEAD is r1935. I don't want to update it yet, but I want a specific change "from the future".

When I run `svn diff -c 1921 .` it show me all the changes.
I could probably take the diff and apply it as a patch, but shouldn `svn merge` do exactly the same? But when I run `svn merge -c 1921 .` nothing happens.

`svn propget svn:mergeinfo` shows nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: create branch from working copy.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a minus in front of `1921`, such as:

```
svn merge -c -1921
```